# Problem in upgrading to Laravel 7.0 / Socilate requirements seems to have been deprecated

Tags: laravel, guzzle, laravel-7, laravel-socialite

I have been trying to upgrade my Laravel application to *Laravel 7.0* from *6.0*.

In the step of package upgrading I am experiencing an issue in Socialite package and logging in with Google through *Socialite* throw out error 500 for me.

I have tried different versions of guzzlehttp/guzzle actually. The latest version which is *7.0* does not have compatibility with *Socialite* requirement named **league/oauth1-client**. In the packagist description it has said that the version needed for this package is >*1.0* and latest version of this package is *1.7* but automatically it installs *leage/oath1-client 1.6.2*. After this installation it downloads guzzle/guzzle package which is deprecated.

Actually I am using guzzlehttp/guzzle but I am getting this warning:

[image]

this is showing why composer use guzzle and leage/oath1-client:

[image: the guzzlehttp/http and leage/oath1-client]

this is my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.2.5",
    "algolia/algoliasearch-client-php": "^2.7",
    "artesaos/seotools": "^0.18",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "^2.19",
    "buzz/laravel-google-captcha": "^2.3",
    "cmgmyr/messenger": "^2.20",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "geoip2/geoip2": "~2.10",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
    "htmlmin/htmlmin": "^7.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.5",
    "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
    "laravel/socialite": "^4.0",
    "laravel/scout": "^8.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravelium/sitemap": "^7.0",
    "mews/purifier": "^3.2",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "pragmarx/tracker": "^4.0",
    "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.11",
    "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.6",
    "spatie/laravel-missing-page-redirector": "^2.6",

    "laravel/helpers": "^1.2",

    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "chencha/share": "dev-master"
},
```

and this is the composer tree for the leage/oath1-client:

[image]

Let me know if any one have overcome this issue, for upgrading Laravel packages.

Comment: Hi! Please do not post screenshots of text, but the text itself. Only use images to show something that can not be described or pasted as text (see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting composer.lock file & vendor folder. Than try composer install again.

Comment: thanks but I have deleted all of them before but no changes.